# bundle size double after migration from material-ui 4 to mui 5

Tags: material-ui, esbuild

we followed the [migration guide](https://mui.com/material-ui/migration/migration-v4/), mostly [running codegen](https://github.com/fixthestatusquo/proca/pull/1205)

we are using esbuild and generate a single file. after the migration, the bundle size went from around 600kb to 1.2Mb.

The material ui part went from just under 200k to more than 750k

We looked at the guidelines on how to optimise bundle size, but unless I missed something, they haven't changed, ie. what treeshaking esbuild was doing on v4 it should be doing on v5.

Any idea on where to look? or is this expected that material ui nearly quadrupled it size?

running the analyzer before:

[image: material-ui 4]

and after:

[image: mui 5]